# Send message to all servers in wazure web farm

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a number of Asp.Net Core 2.x AppService WebApp instances running in Azure.  They all keep a copy of a data object in a local memory cache.

Assume in this scenario that distributed cache is not a feasibility.  As such, I'm looking for a mechanism to send a message/signal to all relevant instances to refresh their memory objects in the local cache.

I can call a rest endpoint to flush the local memory cache, but I'm not sure if there is a way of directing the handling of the call to specific instances.  Is this possible?  If not, is there a workout to letting each instance in the farm know that it's time to expire their cache?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Azure App Service content is stored on Azure Storage and is surfaced up in a durable manner as a content share and the content is shared across multiple virtual machine (VM) instances of the app.

Would the Local cache feature work fine for your requirement: - The Azure App Service Local Cache feature provides a web role view of your content. This content is a write-but-discard cache of your storage content that is created asynchronously on-site startup. When the cache is ready, the site is switched to run against the cached content
If you’re just looking at restart a specific instance in pool, you could leverage Auto-healing feature -  where you could define the triggers in the root web.config file of your web site and configure the actions to be performed when these triggers are hit. 
If you have multiple instances of your web site, it will only log an event for the instance that has hit this trigger and not all instances. Take a look at this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/)  for details.

As a side note, In Azure Portal, navigate to your Azure web app under Diagnose and Solve Problems, search for  -Advanced Application Restart- and you will get an option that allows you to pick just the instance you want. Kindly let me know if this helps or you need further assistance.